# sed variable replacement does not seem to work

Tags: variables, sed

I set up a variable in the shell:

```
-bash-3.00$ echo $source_repl
source ../setup_simple.tcl
```

I then tried to replace a line in a file that started with the string "package require IxLoad" with the variable string (noting that double quotes are the way to get sed to use variable substitution). First I tried with direct substitution (no escaping the $ in the variable):

```
-bash-3.00$ sed -e "s/package require IxLoad.*/$source_repl/g" smtp_tput191Mb.tcl > tmpwatch.tcl
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s'
-bash-3.00$
```

So I thought that escaping the $ would solve the problem but as you can see the line is then replaces by the literal string "$source_repl" rather than the variable stored there:

```
-bash-3.00$ sed -e "s/package require IxLoad.*/\$source_repl/g" smtp_tput191Mb.tcl > tmpwatch.tcl
-bash-3.00$ diff smtp_tput191Mb.tcl tmpwatch.tcl
11c11
< package require IxLoad
---
> $source_repl
-bash-3.00$
```

I looked up many sites on how to do variable substitution in sed and they all seem to indicate that the above should work. What am I missing? Is there something in the actual variable that's causing this?

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time folks. I found the problem. I needed to escape the dots and slashes in the actual variable in order to replace it with the sed statement:

```
-bash-3.00$ echo $source_repl
source \.\.\/setup_simple\.tcl
-bash-3.00$ sed -e "s/package require IxLoad.*/$source_repl/g" smtp_tput191Mb.tcl > tmpwatch.tcl
-bash-3.00$ diff smtp_tput191Mb.tcl tmpwatch.tcl                                          11c11
< package require IxLoad
---
> source ../setup_simple.tcl
-bash-3.00$
```

Thanks

Comment: The dots don't need to be escaped when they're on the right side of an `s///` command.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `/` in your variable. Use @ as pattern separator and this will go.

```
sed -e "s@package require IxLoad.*@$source_repl@g" smtp_tput191Mb.tcl > tmpwatch.tcl
```

Comment: thanks. I just noticed that. I was staring at the problem in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to work this issue around in general (changing the separators is easy, but you never know what can be in the variable), but if you can use `perl` instead of `sed`, you could load the environment variable form inside perl to avoid the escaping issue:

```
perl -pe 's/package require IxLoad.*/$ENV{source_repl}/g' smtp_tput191Mb.tcl > tmpwatch.tcl
```