# sed does not replace the string correctly when using a variable

Tags: string, bash, variables, replace, sed

Currently I have a file that has a unique line with the pattern

```
alphanumeric_ChangeMe_moreAlphaNumeric
```

Actual looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 local.com localhost HostType_test_HostNumber2
```

I'm trying to replace the string test with a variable determined by another command, run as another user using the following code.

```
site=$(su admin -c get_local_site | less | sed 's/Local Site Name: //')
sed -i -e "s/RecoverPoint_[[:alnum:]]*_RPA/RecoverPoint_$site_RPA/" fakehostfile
```

I've tested the individual codes and they echo the correct values, but when I try to use the $site variable in the second it fails to replace the section.

I can't seem to find the correct syntax to replace just what's between the underscores with a string (containing only alphanumerics) that's stored in a variable

I've already been looking on here, and found some similar problems, however the solutions don't seem to work, since part of the replacement string is a variable.  I've tried to concatenate the string as three separate variables, but it replaces things strange (Maybe due to the underscores?)

What am I missing here??

Questions with similar problems that didn't work:

[sed variable replacement does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624561/sed-variable-replacement-does-not-seem-to-work)
[Sed replacement not working when using variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156293/sed-replacement-not-working-when-using-variables)

Comment: why're you using the `-e` option?  `-e`, if I'm correct, should only be used when you're doing something like this: `sed 's/a/b/' -e '/b/d'`.  Also, try using `[a-Z0-9]` instead of `[[:alnum:]]`.

Comment: I want to know why bubthegreat is using `| less`, and not just `admin ... | sed 's/...'` ?  :-) . `-e` doesn't hurt, but not needed. Good luck to all.

Comment: Edited out the less that wasn't actually being used - the -e was because it was recommended when I was searching string replace methods for sed, but removed per suggestions.  Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others recommended, no `less` command required, and if you need show the line of `Local Site Name` only, use -n option in Sed.

Second, put varies in braces, it should fix your problem.

```
site=$(su admin -c get_local_site | sed -n 's/Local Site Name: //p')
sed -i "s/RecoverPoint_[[:alnum:]]*_RPA/RecoverPoint_${site}_RPA/" fakehostfile
```

Comment: Thanks - The less wasn't actually being used at any point in there, I forgot to edit it out after more troubleshooting.  The brackets worked like a charm, thanks!